# Pre-calculating xScale and yScale values for SKNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, sknode

Before executing `[SKAction scaleBy:duration:]` I need to pre-calculate the x scale and y scale of the node.

I am using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to zoom-in/zoom-out my `SKScene`, so I am doing like this (`scale` is the variable which holds `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`'s scale value):

```
[grassLayer runAction:[SKAction group:@[
        [SKAction scaleBy:scale duration:0.0],
        [SKAction moveBy:vector duration:0.0]
]]];
```

Apple documentation says that `scaleBy:duration:` works as follows:

> Creates an action that changes the x and y scale values of a node by a
>   relative value.
>
> Parameters
>
> `scale` The amount to add to the node’s x and y scale values.
>
> `sec` The duration of the animation.

But if I try to calculate future `xScale` and `yScale` like `grassLayer.xScale + scale` it keeps giving me scale values that actually don't "look" like values that `grassLayer` node has after `scaleBy:duration:` method is executed.

So, how can I correctly pre-calculate `xScale`/`yScale` after `scaleBy:duration:` method is executed?

Comment: Could running an if statement inside the `update:` method which checks for the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` be implemented? So whenever the screen is pinched the action will run causing the images to scale.

Comment: @Mutch95, yep, I have also came to this solution... will try to implement this today.